# 'ls' output timestamps different for files in /tmp versus in home directory

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, redhat-enterprise-linux, timestamp

I'm ssh'd into my university Linux servers (RHEL 7). Here's the deal. It has to do with 'ls' and "old" files.

Home directory:

```
$ touch -d '1918-11-11 11:00 GMT' wwi-armistice
$ touch now
$ sleep 1
$ touch now1
$ TZ=UTC0 ls -lt --full-time wwi-armistice now now1
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsai csugrad 0 2054-12-17 17:28:16.000000000 +0000 wwi-armistice
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsai csugrad 0 2018-05-04 22:07:10.743637000 +0000 now1
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsai csugrad 0 2018-05-04 22:06:59.992632000 +0000 now
```

tmp directory:

```
$ tmp=$(mktemp -d)
$ cd $tmp
$ touch -d '1918-11-11 11:00 GMT' wwi-armistice
$ touch now
$ sleep 1
$ touch now1
$ TZ=UTC0 ls -lt --full-time wwi-armistice now now1
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsai csugrad 0 2018-05-04 23:04:27.031485854 +0000 now1
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsai csugrad 0 2018-05-04 23:04:22.907373125 +0000 now
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsai csugrad 0 1918-11-11 11:00:00.000000000 +0000 wwi-armistice
```

I know the reason the first output shows wwi-armistice in 2054 has something to do with signed 32-bit to unsigned 32-bit conversion of Unix time. If someone could confirm that and perhaps explain why (something something nfs?), that would be great.

My second, bigger question is: Why when I do this example in the tmp directory, is wwi-armistice listed correctly?

Keep in mind I don't really know anything about networking, so a basic explanation would be helpful.

Comment: By default `mktemp` will create the directory in `/tmp` which might be a different filesystem than the first case.

Comment: does the fact that I'm connected over network not have anything to do with it?

Comment: When one uses `ssh` to access a login shell on a system, such as you're doing, it is essentially equivalent to logging into the local system from its physical keyboard, but without a GUI.  As such, there's generally no additional 'networking' in play, other than the TCP session that passes terminal input and output between your local system, and the remote server.  Sometimes as a function of the administration policies, your home directory may be mounted from a network file server upon login.  However, `/tmp` is usually a local filesystem, directly connected.

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful if you can identify the filesystems and their mounted options in play here.

`mount` will display the filesystem hierarchy, and mount-time options.

`stat -f --format="%T" $file` will print the filesystem type of the named file.  I suspect the results will be different for the /tmp versions than the ones in (presumably) your home directory.

Once you know the specific filesystem and its mounted options, you can research its timestamp limitations, but I think you've the gist of it: the first filesystem does not have sufficient numerical range in its timestamp byte allocation to represent the 1918 date, while the second one does.